# Trying to add a column to a temp table fails

Tags: t-sql, alter-table

I have looked through this a number of times this morning and cannot find the issue. Its probably dead simple and I'll feel like an idiot when someone points it out. What would this SQL fail?

```
-- Get CurrentRowCount
DECLARE @MaxID INT

SELECT @MaxID = ISNULL(MAX(WorkTypeID),0)
FROM caWorkType

ALTER TABLE #WorkType ADD _RowID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(@MaxID,1)
```

Error I'm getting is: "Incorrect syntax near '@MaxID'" I have checked and @MaxID is being set to 45 by the select statement. The temp table #WorkType also does not have a column named "_RowID"

Comment: Pattern: JIT-SQL, compose the SQL statement in a SQL variable, then execute the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the act of trying to add a column to a temp table that fails, but you cannot use a variable in specifying the values for `IDENTITY`:

**NOT OK**:

```
ALTER TABLE #WorkType ADD _RowID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(@MaxID,1)
```

**OK**:

```
ALTER TABLE #WorkType ADD _RowID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(55,1)
```

Marc

Comment: ah ok! Thanks a million, the code was given to me by a senior and I thought I was stuffing it up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The `IDENTITY` clause doesn't like variables. Use sp_executesql to run the `ALTER` statement:

```
-- Get CurrentRowCount
DECLARE @MaxID INT

SELECT @MaxID = ISNULL(MAX(WorkTypeID),0)
FROM caWorkType

DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #WorkType ADD _RowID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(' +
        CAST(@MaxID as varchar) +
        ',1)';
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sql;
```